# Xamarin Navigation Bar Hide Hamburger Menu

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to hide the hamburger menu on certain pages but still display information in then navbar. I don’t know of any way to accomplish this.

Also, I need the navbar to stay fixed to the top of the screen but it’s getting cut off when the keyboard pops up.

How can I go about this?

Comment: Hi，are you developing `Shell` or `Non-shell` project ?

Comment: It’s a Non-shell project

Comment: Do you want to hide the hamburger icon but still display the nav bar on certain pages?

Comment: Yes that’s exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FlyoutPage.ShouldShowToolbarButton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.flyoutpage.shouldshowtoolbarbutton?view=xamarin-forms) method is used to determine whether to **show/hide** hamburger icon , and it is triggered **every time** when selecting pages.

We can define a `bool` field ,change its value when directing to specific pages.

##### FlyoutPage

```
 public override bool ShouldShowToolbarButton()
        {
            return showIcon;
        }

        private bool showIcon = true;

        private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = e.SelectedItem as FlyoutPage1FlyoutMenuItem;
            if (item == null)
                return;

            var page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType);
            page.Title = item.Title;

            Detail = new NavigationPage(page);
            IsPresented = false;

            FlyoutPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;


            //add this logic
            showIcon = (item.Id == 1) ? false : true;   //only the second page do not show hamburger icon
        }
```

[image]

[image] [image]

Comment: This is exactly what I want but I’m using a Master Detail page, how do I incorporate the FlyOut page into that

Comment: Master detail page is deprecated now , use flyout page instead  , the usage is total same . check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/flyoutpage.