# How to hide Navigation Bar's Hamburger menu icon?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Facing a Navigation bar issue in My content Page. And I set a   **NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"** in xaml Page. But still the Hamburger icon is displayed. Here I attached image for reference[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/citsP.png)

My Xaml Page

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:App1="clr-namespace:com.App1.vetaar"
             x:Class="com.App1.Views.AddScenePage" 
             BackgroundColor="#F8F8F8"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False">
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions></Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label x:Name="backNavButton" Text="Back" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="#1484B8" FontSize="17" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Back_Tapped"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Label x:Name="sceneTitle" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" FontSize="17" FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="Noto Sans CJK JP"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
            <Label x:Name="doneNavButton" Text="Done" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="{OnPlatform Android='0,0,10,0', iOS='0,5,0,0'}" IsVisible="false" TextColor="#1484B8" FontSize="17" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="DoneScene_Tapped"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
        </Grid>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

Xaml.cs

```
  public AddScenePage(Scene scene)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.sceneValue = scene;
            sName.Text = scene.SceneName;
            sImage.Source = scene.BackgroundImage;
            NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
        }
```

Comment: can you attach some code? We can't debug without code :)

Comment: @MarkBarton, I Add a code for Navigation bar for reference

Comment: so are you wanting to add a custom navbar rather that the navbar supplied by Xamarin? Are you using Shell or classic navigation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin Navigation Bar Hide Hamburger Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68840563/xamarin-navigation-bar-hide-hamburger-menu) for more similar Q&As google `site:stackoverflow.com xamarin forms hide navigation bar hamburger icon`.